# Where did the idea of cats having 9 lives come from?

Tags: folklore

Also, a singular cat having 9 lives is an oddly specific number; why not 10 or 12 lives instead? Is this idea more common in European or Asian folklore? Do other animals (dogs, birds, etc) share this attribute of a mythological cat?

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#Superstitions_and_rituals), the number of lives is 7 in some countries (e.g. Germany, Italy) and 6 in some Arabic countries.